# 307 Temporary Redirect On Specific Routes

Tags: apache, http, https, gunicorn, fastapi

I have an api service that i wrote with [FastApi](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) and served with gunicorn. Apache is working on the server as reverse proxy and ssl manage. 
Everything was fine until i decided to use [SqlAdmin](https://github.com/aminalaee/sqladmin) as admin panel. 
The problem is that my api endpoints works fine with SSL but SqlAdmin endpoints are not. 
e.g: Responses i get when i want reach https://example.com/admin: (FAIL)

```
--- I summarized responses ---
307 Temporary Redirect -> http://example.com/admin
302 Not Found
Somehow redirect -> https://example.comadmin/
```

e.g: Responses i get when i want reach https://example.com/users: (PASS) (API ENDPOINT)

```
Request URL: https://example.com/users/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
```

Apache Configuration:

```xml
<VirtualHost ip:80>
 ServerName subdomain.example.com
ServerAlias www.subdomain.example.com
 ServerAdmin ****@gmail.com
Redirect / https://subdomain.example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost ip:443>
 ServerName subdomain.example.com
ServerAlias www.subdomain.example.com
 ServerAdmin ******@gmail.com
ProxyRequests On
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile *****
ProxyPass / http://example.com:8000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com:8000/
<Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Gunicorn Configuration:

```py
import json
import multiprocessing
import os

workers_per_core_str = os.getenv("WORKERS_PER_CORE", "1")
max_workers_str = os.getenv("MAX_WORKERS")
use_max_workers = None
if max_workers_str:
    use_max_workers = int(max_workers_str)
web_concurrency_str = os.getenv("WEB_CONCURRENCY", None)

host = os.getenv("HOST", "0.0.0.0")
port = os.getenv("PORT", "80")
bind_env = os.getenv("BIND", None)
use_loglevel = os.getenv("LOG_LEVEL", "warning")
if bind_env:
    use_bind = bind_env
else:
    use_bind = f"{host}:{port}"

cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
workers_per_core = float(workers_per_core_str)
default_web_concurrency = workers_per_core * cores
if web_concurrency_str:
    web_concurrency = int(web_concurrency_str)
    assert web_concurrency > 0
else:
    web_concurrency = max(int(default_web_concurrency), 2)
    if use_max_workers:
        web_concurrency = min(web_concurrency, use_max_workers)
accesslog_var = os.getenv("ACCESS_LOG", "/var/log/gunicorn/access_log")
use_accesslog = accesslog_var or "/var/log/gunicorn/access_log"
errorlog_var = os.getenv("ERROR_LOG", "/var/log/gunicorn/error_log")
use_errorlog = errorlog_var or "/var/log/gunicorn/error_log"
graceful_timeout_str = os.getenv("GRACEFUL_TIMEOUT", "120")
timeout_str = os.getenv("TIMEOUT", "120")
keepalive_str = os.getenv("KEEP_ALIVE", "5")

# Gunicorn config variables
loglevel = use_loglevel
workers = web_concurrency
bind = use_bind
errorlog = use_errorlog
worker_tmp_dir = "/dev/shm"
accesslog = use_accesslog
graceful_timeout = int(graceful_timeout_str)
timeout = int(timeout_str)
keepalive = int(keepalive_str)


# For debugging and testing
log_data = {
    "loglevel": loglevel,
    "workers": workers,
    "bind": bind,
    "graceful_timeout": graceful_timeout,
    "timeout": timeout,
    "keepalive": keepalive,
    "errorlog": errorlog,
    "accesslog": accesslog,
    # Additional, non-gunicorn variables
    "workers_per_core": workers_per_core,
    "use_max_workers": use_max_workers,
    "host": host,
    "port": port,
}
print(json.dumps(log_data))
```

I dont have any idea how this behavior happend at all so any clue would be helpful :) 
Thanks in advance.

1. I did try to add middleware to the FastApi. [`HTTPSRedirectMiddleware`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/middleware/#httpsredirectmiddleware). 
   every requests reached to this response on gunicorn:
   `WARNING:  Invalid HTTP request received.`
2. I did try to start gunicorn with [--forwarded-allow-ips='*' and --proxy-headers](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/589#issuecomment-599572128). 
   Nothing changed.